# How to make a RewriteRule on Apache .htaccess to fix a broken image?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, rewrite

My page has:

```
<img src="/?cp_contactformtoemail_captcha=captcha&a=1&b=2&c=image.jpg" id="captchaimg_1" alt="security code" border="0">
```

But it should be:

```
<img src="/INDEX.PHP/?cp_contactformtoemail_captcha=captcha&a=1&b=2&c=image.jpg" id="captchaimg_1" alt="security code" border="0">
```

As you can see I need to add `/INDEX.PHP` in front of this image url.

How do I add a RewriteRule to my Apache2 .htaccess to fix that?

1000 Thanks!

Comment: Not a duplicate.

Comment: Uh, yeah, it is.  And what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^(cp_contactformtoemail_captcha.*image.jpg)    /INDEX.PHP/$1
```